# Flutter integration with AWS (With and without Amplify)

Tags: flutter, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

We are building a **Flutter** app which for Web, Android and iOS. We plan to use AWS for backend using services like **Cognito, Dynamodb, S3** and few others.

We have tried to use to Amplify - but understand it is not yet available for Flutter web.

What is best way to connect with Cognito ? and then other services like Dynamodb, S3 etc in AWS

We tried https://pub.dev/packages/amazon_cognito_identity_dart and it is very slow and we are not able to connect.

Answer (score 2):

You should try the a packed based on the one you are mentioning: https://pub.dev/packages/amazon_cognito_identity_dart_2

It worked pretty well for me - I was able to use S3, Lambda, API Gateway, AppSync (with websockets) etc. Note that it does not support Data Store; and if you can live without it - it should work fine.

The only issue is - login is very slow on the web (not on android or ios), there is an open issue about it: https://github.com/furaiev/amazon-cognito-identity-dart-2/issues/123. There seems to be a solution for it now, you may give it a try.

Amplify team implemented Flutter support by using already existing Android and iOS libraries, and just doing the Flutter wrapper around it. I guess it helped them roll it out much faster; but the proper solution (in my opinion) would be to re-write the JavaScript libraries in Dart, and have it compile natively to iOS, Android, Web and all other platforms. My guess is this will come in the future; Amplify Flutter is still in version 0.x.x.